# Does GraphQL Interpret null as truthy?

Tags: graphql

I am trying to use GraphQL (with Gatsby) by pulling data in from a custom API. The API contains data coming from a CMS and the main content is an array of objects. Each object inside that array is a component, with fields like title text, body copy, images, etc.

In GraphQL, I query all the pages for each component and its subfields. GraphQL returns the correct amount of components for each page, but for each component it returns all possible components and related subfields. This means I am getting a lot of `null` objects returned.

Here is my GraphQL query: (contentBlock is what we call a component in the cms)

```
query Demo {
 allPages {
  Pages {
   title
    contentBlocksArray {
      contentBlock {
        introText{
          body
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Here is what gets returned:

```
"allPages": {
  "Pages": [
    {
      "title": "Contact",
      "contentBlocksArray": [
        {
          "contentBlock": {
            "introText": {
              "body": "Get in touch with us"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "contentBlock": {
            "introText": null
          }
        },
        {
          "contentBlock": {
            "introText": null
          }
        },
        {
          "contentBlock": {
            "introText": null
          }
        }
      ]
    },
```

I tried using directives, like this:

```
 allPages {
   Pages {
     title
     contentBlocksArray {
       contentBlock {
         introText @skip(if: false) {
           body
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this did nothing. However, if I switched it to `@skip(if: true)`, the result was unexpected. It returned all `contentBlock` in a page as empty objects, even if `introText` had body copy. Ideally, I would like to see the `introText` object only if `body` was not `null`.

Since `@skip(if:true)` skipped all `introText` even if its value is `null` my conclusion is that GraphQL interprets `null == true` but I'm sure I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the `skip` directive. This directive is executed/evaluated before the query is executed. You can use it to modify static queries depending on variables. The concept of static queries is important for various reasons, there directives give you the opportunity to make minor adjustments late on.

In contrast, it is not working on the data that is returned itself. You can learn more about query directives here: http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#directives